# Ubuntu 18.04 Unable to run indicator-cpufreq

Tags: package-management, 18.04, indicator

1-2 min after every logon the indicator-cpufreq was starting to crash. I reinstalled it and now I can't even start it. Here's the message:

```
  indicator-cpufreq
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:20: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py:21: PyGIWarning: AppIndicator3 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq", line 79, in <module>
    ind = MyIndicator(options.show_frequency)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.update_ui()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/indicator_cpufreq/indicator.py", line 123, in update_ui
    self.select_items[freq].set_active(True)
KeyError: 1468708
```

Is there a way to run it properly and without crashing on ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GNOME, use [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/) GNOME extension to monitor CPU frequency.

Gnome CPU Frequency Monitor and Governor Manager.

This is a lightweight CPU frequency scaling monitor and powerful CPU management tool. The extension is using standard cpufreq kernel modules to collect information and manage governors. It needs root permission to able changing governors.

Features:
⚫ Compatible with many hardware architectures;
⚫ CPU Frequency monitoring;
⚫ CPU Governor management;
⚫ CPU Frequency speed limits;
⚫ CPU Boost supporting;
⚫ CPU Power on/off supporting;
⚫ Saving/Restoring settings...

For more information and how-to see README.md

Extension Homepage
    https://github.com/konkor/cpufreq